# Open and closed localization of sheaves

Tags: math-history, sheaf-theory

In this paper: http://www-math.mit.edu/~hrm/papers/ss.pdf the author claims that Leray originally developed sheaves over closed sets rather than open sets and that it was Cartan who later realized that working with open sets was more *natural*. Why is this? Are there meaningful/essential differences between both approaches?

Edit:

The bounty goes to the person who can answer all the previous questions and elaborates a little bit more.

I have the feeling that **maybe**, since Leray was working on functional analysis, he was thinking about subspaces, hence the closure condition.

Comment: I don't know anything about this, but a possibility that comes to mind is that may be Leray wanted to deal with objects with compact support. On a manifold a closed subset of a compact set is again compact, so you may avoid some problems that way. As Qiaocu explains we do want the intersections to have non-empty interiors for the agreement on intersections to be a strong enough condition.

Answer (score 2):

Many important examples are naturally defined on open sets and not closed sets. For example, consider the sheaf of differentiable functions on a smooth manifold, or the sheaf of holomorphic functions on a complex manifold: these are naturally conditions that you check on open subsets, and it's not even clear what it means to check them on closed subsets.

It also seems to be more natural to talk about open covers rather than closed covers, e.g. the condition that you have a pair of functions on $U$ and $V$ that agree on $U \cap V$ is much stronger if $U, V$ are open (since then $U \cap V$ will also be open) than if $U, V$ are closed. For example, on an $n$-dimensional manifold, an open subset is always also an $n$-dimensional manifold, but a closed subset doesn't even need to be a manifold, and could even be as small as a point. So the condition that you have two sections on $U$ and on $V$ that agree on $U \cap V$ is potentially much weaker.

Comment: I see your point, but I think there must've been a (good) reason for Leray to work originally with closed sets. Do you know anything about this?